# Overriding a third-party module's logger?

Tags: python, logging

I'm not sure how to explain the issue, but I think that a third-party module that I'm using is preventing me from using a logger the "normal" way.

I'm currently using a third-party module called [Stanza](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/stanza/). Whenever I load the module and the resources I believe a logger is initialized.

When I try to set up my own logger, it doesn't seem to work. Here's my code:

```
import logging 

import stanza


logger = logging.getLogger()


def main():
    stanza.download('en', package='craft')
    stanza_pipeline = stanza.Pipeline('en', package='craft')

    logging_msg_fmt = '[%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(filename)s: %(lineno)d (%(funcName)s)] %(message)s'
    logging.basicConfig(format=logging_msg_fmt, level=logging.INFO, handlers=[logging.FileHandler(), \
        logging.StreamHandler()])

    logger.info("Logging message.")
```

This code outputs what I assume to be Stanza's own logger output and my own logger statements don't work. In fact, when I do `print(logger)` I get `<RootLogger root (WARNING)>`.

Is there any way that I can go around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your basicConfig call to before stanza is imported.

[Where stanza messes up](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/stanza/blob/main/stanza/__init__.py)

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a same issue, I had already declared in my **main.py** the basic configurations for logging:

```
logging.basicConfig(handlers=[logging.FileHandler("log.log", 'a+', 'utf-8'),logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)],
                        format="%(asctime)s-%(name)s-%(filename)s->%(funcName)s()->%(lineno)d: [%(levelname)s] - %(message)s",
                        level=logging.DEBUG, datefmt="%d-%b-%y %H:%M:%S")
```

and then when I imported a specific module X in my other python file, that specific module was setting the level logging to **Error** so only Error logs were being shown in my logs.

I discovered that **basicConfig** method has a parameter named **force** which overwrites the handlers already configured in the root logger if its value is **True**.

Using this it worked for me:

```
logging.basicConfig(handlers=[logging.FileHandler("log.log", 'a+', 'utf-8'),logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)],
                        format="%(asctime)s-%(name)s-%(filename)s->%(funcName)s()->%(lineno)d: [%(levelname)s] - %(message)s",
                        level=logging.DEBUG, datefmt="%d-%b-%y %H:%M:%S", force=True)
```